# jQuery Mobile and PhoneGap - lifespan of a JavaScript variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova

I'm building a PhoneGap with jQuery. My question is fairly simple, if I create a variable in JavaScript, how long does that variable remain accessible?

For example, if I build my app which has a variable `var foo=5` (a JavaScript variable), then compile with PhoneGap and install on a phone, how long will `foo` be available? I mean, the user will open the app, do stuff, close the app, re-open, close, etc. etc. Does `foo` stay in memory as holding the value 5?

My initial suspicion is that `foo` will exist so long as the user doesn't delete the PhoneGap app off of their phone. Is that correct?

Comment: Are you asking about JavaScript or Java?

Comment: JavaScript (edited to say JavaScript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set the variable in your code (i.e. `var foo = 5;`), the variable will be persistent indefinitely.

If you set the value of the variable from within your application (i.e. `var foo;` then after some action, `foo = 5;`), the variable will persist until you either 1) set it again or 2) completely stop and restart your application.

Comment: When you say "completely stop and restart your application" I assume that means if the user actually stops the app on their phone and not just pressing the "home" button. My understanding is that hitting the home button simply puts the app into the background, so its still running. If this is the case, then from what you say, the variable would persist indefinitely until the user either forces the app to stop, or they actually delete the app. Correct?

Comment: You are correct. When the app goes into the background your variable will still persist

Comment: Does Phonegap take care of that? Because in "normal" Android you would need to think about persisting in the appropriate lifecycle callbacks.

Comment: But if the variables are created outside of a function, then they persist. My `foo` variable, for example, outside of any functions. So, I don't think I have to worry about them persisting in the appropriate lifecycle callbacks since they (the variables) are declared outside of any async function calls. I think that's what you're referring to.

Answer (score 0):

A Javascript variable is alive while the page is alive. When you redirect somewhere or reload the page your javascript variable will no longer exist.

If you have

```
var foo = 5;
```

in your script and you reload the page, you will see the foo variable, but it is recreated since you have reloaded the page. You can store long-term Javascript values in [local storage](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html). Basically, when you load a page, all your javascript files included into the html will load.

Comment: Yes, but I'm talking about the variable lifespan in a PhoneGap app. Since PhoneGap takes HTML, JavaScript, and CSS and builds a native app, I'm curious how this all plays out once this variable is part of the native app. So, I know the variable's lifespan matches that of the webpage (as you indicate) but what about when that same variable is now part of a compiled PhoneGap app? That's what I'm curious about.